# How to find the locations of your labels, especially multiple defined ones in Overleaf or Latex in general?

Tags: overleaf, multiple-files, search

Working on my theses, I get the `Label multiply defined` warning. This can happen and is no big issue, however right now my thesis is rather long and divided into several subfiles. I can't find the second definition, so I would have to go through each document and `CTR-F` the label.

Is there some functionality (in Overleaf) to find the label in question? Within the logs, it only appears in the error message....

Comment: Found it in the meanwhile, by commenting out subfile links one by one and so narrowing down the search. Anyways, question remains :)

Comment: If you look in the aux file, every \label will correspond to a \newlabel command.  The last argument should be the page number.

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks, do you know how to retrieve the aux file in an overleaf project?

Comment: @RolandDeschain If you want to find the aux file in an Overleaf project, go to your project and compile it. Right beside your green compile button, there should be an icon that resembles a page. Click on that icon (Logs and output files) and then click the bottom-right blue button with the text "Other logs and files". A dropdown list will appear, and you should be able to see `output.aux` listed. Click on the file and it will download the file locally to your machine.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Actually, the page is the second argument after the label name (right after the `\@currentlabel`)

Comment: Some editors have features like this. TeXstudio for example presents multiple defined labels with a different color, you can see labels on the left panel and also navigate between them clicking on the line of its *log* panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% changes number of arguments for \newlabel

\newcommand{\listoflabels}{}
\let\normalnewlabel=\newlabel
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newlabel}[2]{%
  \protected@edef\listoflabels{\listoflabels label(#1) page(\getpagelabel#2)\protect\par}%
  \global\let\listoflabels=\listoflabels
  \normalnewlabel{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\IfPackageLoadedTF{hyperref}{\def\getpagelabel#1#2#3#4#5{#2}}% see also cleveref
  {\def\getpagelabel#1#2{#2}}

\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}
\listoflabels

\refstepcounter{foo}\label{bar}

\refstepcounter{foo}\label{bar}

\pageref{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I trust it works :)